# Медленное выполнение кода — подбрасывание монетки миллиард раз

Tags: python, производительность

Такой, к примеру, код всего лишь на миллиард итераций выполняется у меня час (60 минут) - что я делаю не так?

```
import random


reshka = 0
orel = 0
i = 0
while i < 1000000000: 
    coin = random.randint(0, 1)
    if coin > 0: 
        reshka += 1
    else:
        orel += 1
    i += 1
print('reshek', reshka, 'orlov', orel)

input()
```

Comment: На i5-2500 на w8 выполняется со скоростью примерно миллион итераций / 1.4-1.5с. Думаю, почему-то медленно считается randint.

Comment: Учитывайте также что функция print тоже забирает время.

Comment: @kal1sha она не в цикле

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ты используешь Питон - интерпретируемый скриптовый язык, вот что ты делаешь не так! =D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Можно *без изменений* запустить на [Pypy](http://pypy.org/), в котором присутствует `JIT`-компилятор (51 секунда):

```
$ /usr/bin/time pypy .
('reshek', 499987397, 'orlov', 500012603)
50.67user 0.00system 0:50.71elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 37004maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+3409minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Или переписать код, чтобы запросить весь миллиард сразу на обычной реализации (СPython):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

N = 10**9
n = random.getrandbits(N)
popcount = bin(n).count("1")
print("heads: %d tails: %d" % (popcount, (N - popcount)))
```

Этот вариант заметно быстрее (8 секунд):

```
$ /usr/bin/time python heads-n-tails.py
heads: 499999280 tails: 500000720
7.26user 0.13system 0:07.40elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1115464maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+3053minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: В Питон 3.10 bit_count метод появился: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count

Answer (score 23):

**Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на ответ [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/5577), его решение эффективнее моего.**

Для того, чтобы выяснить, что именно тормозит вашу программу, можно использовать профайлер. Он поставляется вместе с Python, документацию можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). Посмотрим, что не так с вашей программой:

```
python -m cProfile -s time test.py
```

Для ускорения проверки я уменьшил количество итераций до 1000000. Профайлер выдаст что-то вроде этого:

```
     6002902 function calls (6002874 primitive calls) in 3.848 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000    1.162    0.000    2.728    0.000 random.py:165(randrange)
  1000000    0.992    0.000    1.566    0.000 random.py:216(_randbelow)
        1    0.694    0.694    3.848    3.848 test.py:1(<module>)
  2002055    0.518    0.000    0.518    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.Random' objects}
  1000000    0.422    0.000    3.150    0.000 random.py:210(randint)
  1000000    0.056    0.000    0.056    0.000 {method 'bit_length' of 'int' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method load_dynamic}
       16    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method stat}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 {built-in method print}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method loads}
      ...
```

Как и ожидалось, больше всего времени потребляет генерация случайного числа методом `randint`. Как видно из вывода профайлера, много времени занимает проверка на вхождение числа в интервал. Также странно выглядит количество вызовов `getrandbits` - в 2 раза больше, чем нужно. Генерацию случайного целого от 0 до 1 можно ускорить, сразу использовав [`getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits):

```
coin = random.getrandbits(1)
```

Таким образом мы избавляемся от лишних вычислений и получаем заметный прирост производительности:

```
         1000847 function calls (1000819 primitive calls) in 0.837 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.440    0.440    0.837    0.837 test.py:1(<module>)
  1000000    0.237    0.000    0.237    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.Random' objects}
        2    0.093    0.046    0.094    0.047 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1031(get_data)
        1    0.062    0.062    0.062    0.062 {built-in method load_dynamic}
        2    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method init_builtin}
        2    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {method 'read' of '_io.FileIO' objects}
       16    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method stat}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method print}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method loads}
 ...
```

Врочем, с миллиардом итераций программа всё равно будет работать медленно. Изначально я предположил, что производительность упирается в Питоновский генератор случайных чисел, и переписал программу так, чтобы вызывался генератор из сишной библиотеки:

```
from ctypes import cdll
libc = cdll.msvcrt

reshka = 0
orel = 0

for i in range(1000000):
    coin = libc.rand() % 2
    if coin > 0: 
        reshka += 1
    else:
        orel += 1
```

Но это не дало никакого прироста производительности:

```
         1753 function calls (1703 primitive calls) in 0.753 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.744    0.744    0.753    0.753 test.py:1(<module>)
        2    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001 {built-in method load_dynamic}
       32    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method stat}
       37    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method __build_class__}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method print}
        4    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method loads}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1031(get_data)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method OpenKey}
       19    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1352(find_loader)
       71    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:74(_path_join)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 __init__.py:1(<module>)
      ...
```

Тогда я набросал аналогичную программу на C и измерил скорость её работы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int heads = 0, tails = 0, i = 0;
    srand(0);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        if (rand() %2) {
            heads++;
        } else {
            tails++;
        }
    }

    printf("Heads: %d Tails: %d", heads, tails);
    return 0;
}
```

Её выполнение заняло 0.045 секунды. С миллиардом итераций - 16.98 секунды. Отсюда напрашивается вывод: в Python слишком велики накладные расходы на интерпретацию программы. Не важно, как быстро выполняются критические секции программы - вы всё равно получаете приличное замедление только за счёт того, что Python - интерпретируемый язык. Возможно, выполнение кода можно ускорить, использовав Cython или PyPy, но нужно ли это? Если да - почитайте [эту статью](http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/speeding-up-your-python-code/), там даётся вводная информация по оптимизации программ на Python.

Comment: «CPython» — может, имелся в виду Cython?

Comment: @andreymal, CPython - это вполне официальное название реализации python

Comment: @Etki стнадартной реализации, используемой по умолчанию и как раз тормозящей в данном вопросе. Крайне нелогично советовать её для ускорения.

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения

Comment: @fori1ton выводы в данном ответе неверны. Сравните производительность CPython  кода из [моего ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/23044) и вашего C кода. В сторону: я не уверен, что `rand()%2` в вашем коде имеет хорошие статические свойства ([посмотрите на картинку как легко неслучайный результат получить](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash/1195035#comment40737683_1195035)). Можно пару слов сказать явно, почему bias из-за `% n` в данном случае не важен.

Comment: @jfs, да, с этим я полностью согласен, ваш ответ лучше. Мне не пришло в голову решать задачу НЕ в лоб, оттого и решение не самое оптимальное. Помещу, пожалуй, ссылку на ваш ответ в начало своего, чтобы не вводить людей в заблуждение.

Answer (score 6):

Можно привлечь модуль [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) для генерации случайных чисел и таким образом уменьшить время до примерно 20 секунд без задействования дополнительных компиляторов.

```
import numpy, time

def test(n):
    t1 = time.time()
    n2 = n / (10**7) # если нет сотни гигабайт оперативки, то придется считать частями
    reshka = 0
    orel = 0
    while n2 > 0:
        rnd = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, 10**7)
        nonzero = numpy.count_nonzero( rnd )
        orel += nonzero # орел - 1 , то есть не ноль
        reshka += 10**7 - nonzero
        n2 -= 1
    t2 = time.time()
    print(reshka, orel, t2 - t1)

test(10**9)
```

Результат:

```
500004947 499995053 19.711090803146362
```

То есть 20 секунд без особых ухищрений, кроме NumPy. При этом время выполнения соизмеримо с результатом на С, в ответе @for1ton

Comment: [код в моём ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/23044) (без задействования дополнительных компиляторов) выполняется за 8 секунд.

Comment: Извините, не заметил

Answer (score 0):

Интересная задача. Можно попробовать не использовать циклы и задействовать только один вызов `random`. За 5 минут набросал что-то такое:

```py
from random import randrange
from math import sqrt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global ans
    ans = None

    n = 10**9
    r = randrange(0, n * 2 + 1)

    if r < n:
        ans = n // 2 - sqrt(r)
    else:
        ans = n // 2 + sqrt(r - n // 2)

    print(int(ans), n - int(ans))
```

Идея в том, что бросая  монетку миллиард раз мы получаем случайное число от одного до миллиарда. Чем ближе число к полмиллиарду, тем больше шанс его получить.

Не уверен что реализовал все точно со стороны математики.

Comment: Можете пояснить, в чём смысл кода? Откуда берётся деление на 2 и корни? Код из вопроса 2 числа выводит, а этот - одно

Comment: @dIm0n Теперь 2 числа выводит, поправил. На счет делений на 2 и взятия корней. Как я написал в ответе, я пытаюсь взять случайное число от 0 до миллиарда. Но я хочу сделать так, что шанс выпадения числа близкому к полмиллиарду был выше, чем шанс выпадения числа далекого от полмиллиарда. Для этого и использую ```sqrt```. Почему  именно ее, потому лучше ничего не придумал. Думаю с точки зрения математики существует более подходящая.

Comment: Можно использовать нормальное распределение вместо равномерного

Comment: @dIm0n не очень понял что вы называете распределением?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нормальное_распределение

Comment: @dIm0n я конечно не успел прочитать всю статью, но судя по графикам да, оно лучше подходит

Comment: А как этот ответ относится к вопросу о производительности?