# Как на Python быстро сгененрировать 10.000.000 случайных адресов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, производительность

Время генерации около 1 минуты. Очень много времени сжирает `random.randint`. Пока что время 6 минут. Может быть есть какой то модуль для ускорения?
Адреса нужно сгенерировать домашние. Почтовый индекс должен соответствовать реальному городу. В частности, вот код для российского региона:

```
def rufunction(records, error):
    country = open('E:\\programming\\base\\country.txt').readline().split(' ')[0]
    splitnames = open('E:\\programming\\base\RU\\nameRU.txt').readline().split(' ')
    splitsurnames = open('E:\\programming\\base\RU\\surnameRU.txt').readline().split(' ')
    splitcities = open('E:\\programming\\base\RU\\cityRU.txt').readline().split(' ')
    splitstreets = open('E:\\programming\\base\RU\\streetRU.txt').readline().split(' ')
    fullist = set()

    while int(records) > 0:
        cityandzip = random.choice(splitcities)
        street = random.choice(splitstreets)
        name = random.choice(splitnames)
        surname = random.choice(splitsurnames)

        fullname = name + ' ' + surname

        address = cityandzip.split('-')[1] + '%03d' % random.randint(0, 999) + ', ' + country + ', ' + \
                  cityandzip.split('-')[0] + ', ' + street + ', ' + str(random.randint(1, 100))
        telnumber = "+7-%03d-%03d-%02d-%02d" % (random.randint(900, 999), random.randint(0, 999),
                                                random.randint(0, 99), random.randint(0, 99))

        record = address + ', ' + fullname + ', ' + telnumber

        fullist.add(record)
        records = int(records) - 1
```

Моя идея такова была. Создаю файлы, в котором есть набор случайных данных, из него беру рандомную запись, затем все объединяю в результат.

Comment: ip4 адресов? адресов электронной почты? мак адресов? географических?

Покажите свой код. Может его проще оптимизировать.

Comment: Если нужна скорость, то почему бы на си/с++ написать простенькую прогу, которая в файл поместит адреса, а вы уже из файла скриптом вытащите? Или сделать dll в которой будут сгенерированы, а сама dll будет импортироваться и использоваться скриптом. Смотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432934/

Comment: как минимум генерацию телефонного номера бы сделал одни рандомом. И потом разделял.

Comment: @Anton M, Ваш вопрос на самом деле довольно интересен. В нем много воды, но суть проста: нужно ускорить получение случайных чисел. Если Вам помог какой-то ответ, примите его. Удалив вопрос Вы лишите других пользователей возможности получить решение в схожей проблеме.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: генерацию всех случайных чисел можно к одному `random.getrandbits()` свести—столько то бит для индекса cities, столько то для streets, столько для телефонного номера  ([это может заметно ускорить процесс](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/23044)). Затем дело только в форматировании (относительно трудоёмко), если вы собираетесь писать это в файл, то производительность от скорости диска может зависеть. Какие размеры входных списков (может лучше `itertools.product(names, surnames, cities, streets)` использовать). Как вы дальше хотите `full_list` использовать?

Answer (score 8):

Если хотите ускорить генерацию случайных чисел - используйте [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

```
import numpy, time
def test():
    t1 = time.time()
    # заполняем массив размером 10000000 случайными числами от 0 до 999
    rnd = numpy.random.randint(0,999,(10000000)) 
    t2 = time.time()
    print( t2-t1 )
test()
```

Результат:

```
0.191633939743042
```

Далее получаете значения из этого массива, а не вызывая каждый раз функцию генерации случайного числа.

Для полноты картины те же 10млн случайных чисел, полученных с помощью `random.randint`:

```
import random, time
def test2():
    t1 = time.time()
    rnd = [ random.randint(0,999) for i in range(10000000) ]
    t2 = time.time()
    print( t2-t1 )
test2()
```

Результат на моем компьютере в 127 раз дольше:

```
24.371521949768066
```