# Непонятное замедление конкатенации в цикле

Tags: python, многопоточность, строки, циклы, производительность

Всем добра.

Приходит строка байт `buffered_img` длиной 786'432 байта (`Grayscale 8bit` изображение `1024x768`). Запускается обработчик в отдельном потоке (если считать в основном потоке, то просто виснет окно). Алгоритм такой: берется 0-вой пиксель из оригинального изображения (первый байт из строки `buffered_img`), проверяется его 7-ой бит, если он равен 0, то к строке `nine['img_7']` дописывается байт `'\x00'`, если 1, то `'\xff'`, затем берется 6-ой бит 0-го пикселя, также проверяется и дописывается к `nine['img_6']` и т.д. до 0 бита. Эта операция повторяется для всех пикселей. В итоге получаем 9 изображений: оригинальное + 8 генерированных.

Так вот, проблема в том, что с каждой операцией конкатенации, процесс замедляется, ползунок `QProgressBar` (PyQt5), который завязан на сигнал `generating`, ползет все медленнее и медленнее с каждым процентом, хотя поначалу все идет бодро. Если бы проценты капали с самого начала медленно, претензий бы не возникло, но на лицо явное замедление процесса конкатенации, и моего скудного опыта в программировании не хватает, для того, чтобы объяснить это явление. Кто подскажет, в чем проблема? Вот кусочки кода:

```
# Глобальный словарь с байт-строками генерированных картинок
nine = {'img_7': b'', 'img_6': b'', 'img_5': b'', 'img_4': b'',
    'img_3': b'', 'img_2': b'', 'img_1': b'', 'img_0': b''}
b0 = pack('B', 0)
b255 = pack('B', 255)

# Метод run() QThread в котором buffered_img - байт строка с оригинальным изображением
def run(self):
    global nine, img_str
    self.start_gen.emit(len(buffered_img))
    pb_val = 0
    for img in nine:
        nine[img] = b''
    for byte_ in buffered_img:
        pb_val += 1
        self.generating.emit(pb_val)
        bit_str = self.by2bi(byte_)
        for i in range(8):
            if bit_str[i] == '0':
                nine['img_' + str(i)] += b0
            else:
                nine['img_' + str(i)] += b255
    self.stop_gen.emit()

# Подсмотренный где-то код, на выходе выдает строку типа ('10110100' для
# входного байта '\xb4'
def by2bi(self, bytestring):
    try:
        bits = bin(int(hexlify(bytestring), 16))[2:]
        data = bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))
        del bits
        return data
    except ValueError:
        print 'Error bytes2bits decode!'
```

Comment: Можно заранее выделить список/массив/numpy массив нужного размера, и в него писать, тогда по идее не должно тормозить.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста подсказать, каким образом это сделать?
И, если я правильно понял, потом необходимо из этого массива ''.join() делать? В чем тогда выигрышь? Или QImage необязательно строку берет в качестве источника данных? И все-таки, было бы интересно узнать, почемсу такая долгая конкатенация? К длинной строке прицепить один байт, неужели это сложно?

Comment: По совету, начал писать в  bytearray(), все получается гораздо быстрее, однако все еще возникает вопрос, почему со строками так медленно?

Comment: @insolor, спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: в сторону (не относится к проблеме): чтобы узнать сброшен ли бит, не нужно [в "01"-строку превращать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279). Вместо этого можно побитовые операции над байтом проводить. К примеру, чтобы проверить, установлен ли `i`-ый бит в `byte_` целом числе: `(byte_ >> i) & 1`

Comment: Для вычислений, картинки как numpy массивы можно в программе представлять, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916760/4279)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что вы используете квадратичный алгоритм [O(n<sup>2</sup>)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5):

```
байтовая_строка = b""
for byte_ in buffered_img:
    байтовая_строка += b"data" * byte_
```

Байтовые строки в Питоне неизменяемы, поэтому каждая `+=` операция создаёт новую всё бо́льшую строку (O(n) операция, требующая времени пропорционально текущей длине строки) — как маляр из анекдота: ["Ничего не могу поделать—Каждый день я ухожу все дальше и дальше от банки!"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) ([перевод](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/BacktoBasics.html)). `n` умножить на O(n) операций делает весь цикл O(n<sup>2</sup>) алгоритмом.

Первое улучшение: используйте линейный алгоритм O(n):

```
result = bytearray()
for byte_ in buffered_img:
    result += b"data" * byte_
байтовая_строка = bytes(result)
```

В этом случае `+=` операция добавляет от 0 до 4*255 байт в конец одного и того же `result` массива, не создавая его каждый раз заново. `+=` операция в этом случае `O(1)` (амортизировано) — требует постоянного времени, не зависящего от длины `buffered_img`, поэтому весь цикл занимает `n` умножить на  O(1), то есть O(n), что гораздо лучше чем O(n<sup>2</sup>). Для обычных строк (str), можно использовать список вместо `bytearray()` и добавив отдельные строки с помощью `list_of_strings.append(s)`, результат **`''.join(list_of_strings)`** (это гарантирует линейный алгоритм).

В обоих примерах (c байтовой строкой и с bytearray) память растёт, и не смотря на идентичный код в цикле, один пример это квадратичный алгоритм, а другой линейный. Разница в том по какому алгоритму выделяется память — в одном случае всегда ровно сколько нужно (под новую байтовую строку) на каждой итерации, а в другом на величину пропорциональную текущему размеру (увеличивается место для массива), только когда размер дорастает до ёмкости. К примеру, [`ArrayList<T>` в Java в полтора раза](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100359/4279) увеличивает ёмкость каждый раз при заполнении, [Python list ~1.125](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100449/4279) — именно это позволяет избежать квадратичного поведения (если бы к массив увеличивался на каждой итерации, то получился бы O(n<sup>2</sup>)  алгоритм из-за O(n) худшего случая для `realloc()` — фактическая производительность зависит от реализации realloc() на выбранной платформе, к примеру, выключение `1.125` умножения для `bytearray()` на моей Linux машине не изменило существенно результаты измерений). Уже для умеренных размеров порядка 10<sup>6</sup> возможно появление квадратичного поведения из-за отсутствия overallocation при вызове realloc() для строк: [Why does naive string concatenation become quadratic above a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44487537/4279)

[Подробнее о конкатенации строк от создателя Питона](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/). Статья очень старая, поэтому детали, связанные с реализацией, могут отличаться на современном Питоне (к примеру, CPython может иногда автоматически оптимизировать конкатенацию строк), но общие принципы оптимизации остались прежними: не пытайтесь оптимизировать  без измерений производительности, используйте profiler, проверяйте на [квадратичность](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/) ваши алгоритмы, меньше кода — лучше, перемещайте «горячие циклы» в C.

#### Сравнение производительности

Квадратичный алгоритм:

```
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s 'buffered_img = b"\x01" * 10_000' '
байтовая_строка = b"" 
for byte_ in buffered_img:
    байтовая_строка += b"data" * byte_'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 14.2 ms +- 0.5 ms
```

Линейный:

```
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s 'buffered_img = b"\x01" * 10_000' '
result = bytearray()
for byte_ in buffered_img:
    result += b"data" * byte_
байтовая_строка = bytes(result)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 932 us +- 18 us
```

Если увеличить размер `buffered_img` в десять раз, то время исполнения линейного алгоритма увеличится примерно в десять раз (с 0.9 ms до 9 ms):

```
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s 'buffered_img = b"\x01" * 100_000' '
result = bytearray()
for byte_ in buffered_img:
    result += b"data" * byte_
байтовая_строка = bytes(result)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 9.43 ms +- 0.35 ms
```

Время для квадратичного алгоритма увеличивается примерно в сто раз (с 0.014s до 2s):

```
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s 'buffered_img = b"\x01" * 100_000' '
байтовая_строка = b""  
for byte_ in buffered_img: 
    байтовая_строка += b"data" * byte_' 
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 2.05 sec +- 0.06 sec
```

*Чем длиннее `buffered_img` тем хуже квадратичный алгоритм по сравнению с линейным* (для `len(buffered_img)` ~ 100_000 на два порядка разница ~10ms против ~2000 ms).

---

В CPython, "+=" реализуется `INPLACE_ADD` инструкцией интерпретатора и для аргументов `str` типа, на которые нет ссылок в других частях кода, используется оптимизация (`realloc()` вызывается) и, даже без экспоненциального роста размера новой памяти, измерения демонстрируют линейное поведение для str типа на моей Linux машине (увеличение длины в 10 раз увеличивает время примерно в 10 раз):

```
$ python3  -mtimeit $'s = ""\nfor _ in range(10000): s+= "a"'
200 loops, best of 5: 1.21 msec per loop
$ python3  -mtimeit $'s = ""\nfor _ in range(100000): s+= "a"'
20 loops, best of 5: 12.1 msec per loop
$ python3  -mtimeit $'s = ""\nfor _ in range(1000000): s+= "a"'
2 loops, best of 5: 120 msec per loop
```

О том как `realloc()` на Linux реализован [A Story of Realloc (and Laziness)](http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2014/04/05/a-story-of-realloc-and-laziness/)([перевод](https://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/238739/)).

Для unicode типа на Питоне 2 и для bytes типа на Питоне 3 на текущих версиях нет оптимизации "+=" (исходная строка всегда копируется в `PyUnicode_Concat()` и `bytes_concat()` соответственно) — квадратичное поведение (увеличение длины в 10 раз, увеличивает время примерно в 100 раз):

```
$ python3  -mtimeit $'s = b""\nfor _ in range(10000): s+= b"a"'
100 loops, best of 5: 3.81 msec per loop
$ python3  -mtimeit $'s = b""\nfor _ in range(100000): s+= b"a"'
1 loop, best of 5: 352 msec per loop
$ python3  -mtimeit $'s = b""\nfor _ in range(1000000): s+= b"a"'
1 loop, best of 5: 46.6 sec per loop
```

#### Другие улучшения

Использование правильного алгоритма как правило важнее других факторов, но ещё можно улучшить константу алгоритма (функция роста времени та же, но каждая операция быстрее), используя numpy, чтобы *выполнять операцию над несколькими байтами одновременно*, пример: [`a_out[::2] = a_in << 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15911233/4279). Или перенести эти операции в Сython, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583392/23044). Ещё пример кода, который заменяет Питон-цикл, [кодом, который на уровне C с отдельными байтами работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/23044). Ещё пример, где [улучшение производительности тем же способом достигается](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16308989/4279).

Перенос Питон-цикла в С расширения (numpy, Cython, random.getrandbits(), bin(), bytes.translate() в примерах) также позволяет несколько CPU ядер задействовать при использовании потоков  в СPython (GIL может освобождаться на время вычислений в C).

Comment: Количество (само число) ваших качественных ответов здесь впечатляет! ;-) Думаю вы заслужили плюсик и новую звезду. :-)