# Как прочитать последнюю строку и дописать данные

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, файлы

Имеются большие файлы от 5мб и выше, к примеру 1 файл содержит 114320 строк.

Необходимо считать последнюю или предпоследнюю строку (если в последней был символ новой строки), и дописать новые данные. Видел разные реализации, но все они предполагают, что файл будет маленький.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Get last n lines of a file with Python, similar to tail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136168/4279)

Comment: 5MB или 100K строк это относительно маленькие данные: начните с самого простого кода, который работает в вашем случае.

Comment: @jfs если использовать цикл который переходит по строкам то это занимает непростительно много времени, необходимо что-то побыстрее, есть такое? можно ли как-то с конца читать фаил? можно было бы наткнуться на символ переноса строки и понять что последнюю строку уже нашли

Comment: Попробуйте на ссылку нажать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы прочитать последнюю строку в относительно небольшом файле:

```
from collections import deque

with open('файл.txt') as file:
     [last_line] = deque(file, maxlen=1) or ['']
```

Большой файл можно с конца читать пока новая строка не встретится, используя [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html):

```
from mmap import mmap, ACCESS_READ

def last_line(filename, newline=b'\n'):
    with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as file:
        try:
            s = mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ)
        except ValueError:  # empty
            return b''
        else:
            with s:
                i = s.rfind(newline, 0, -1)
                return s[i + len(newline) if i != -1 else 0:]
```

Этот вариант возвращает байты и не поддерживает режим универсальных строк. Пример:

```
>>> last_line('no newline.txt')
b'abc'
```

Для чтения пары строк с конца, ещё может подойти, к примеру, [`tail(file, n)` функция из @A. Coady ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280083/4279). Размер буфера в ответе удваивается по схожей причине, описанной в [Непонятное замедление конкатенации в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/23044) — при чтении с конца нужно быть осторожным, чтобы не сделать ваш алгоритм квадратичным случайно:

```
def last_line(filename, newline=b'\n'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        size, s = 2, b''
        while s.find(newline, 0, -1) == -1:  # until a full line is read
            try:
                file.seek(-size, os.SEEK_END)
            except IOError:  # file is too small
                file.seek(0)  # rewind to beginning
                break
            finally:
                s = file.read(size)
            size *= 2
        i = s.rfind(newline, 0, -1)
        return s[i + len(newline) if i != -1 else 0:]
```

Сравните  производительность (включая `deque()` вариант), чтобы узнать какое решение лучше работает в вашем случае.

Comment: А прямо по адресу в файле читать блоки по 4К  с конца  и искать в них `\n` в Python сложно?

Comment: @avp [самый популярный ответ по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136368/4279) уже по блокам читает (это относительно сложный вариант. last_line(), реализованная по идеям tail() из A. Coady ответа, — проще).

Comment: На Си я бы возвращал из подобной функции позицию и длину. Если содержимое реально потребуется, то вызывающая сторона может сама прочесть его в реально существующую у нее область памяти. Но, конечно, это уже все из области "философских" вопросов разработки.

Comment: @avp: в Питоне функция `last_line()` возвращает последнюю строку, вместо позиции последней строки в файле :) Последнее обновление показывает ещё одно достоинством методов в ответе: легко добавить поддержку многобайтных разделителей строк (в варианте с блоками пришлось бы ещё больше усложнить код, чтобы правильно разделитель, попавший на границу между блоками отловить).

Comment: И вы на практике встречали такие разделители? (очевидно, что `\n` в кодировках UTF-16 и UCS-32 не будет разрезан)

Comment: @avp конечно, `len(os.linesep) > 1` на Windows. Бывает полезно свои записи иметь, к примеру, чтобы вывод shell по prompt разделить (функциональность в pexpect можно встретить). See also, [Add support for reading records with arbitrary separators to the standard IO stack](https://bugs.python.org/issue1152248)

Comment: В самом деле, есть такое. Я даже когда-то делал это  в своей версии `getline()`, но уже очень давно не использовал. Согласен, эта штука усложнит код чтения сзади-наперед. Придется сохранять состояние между чтениями блоков. Кстати, так из вашей ссылки на Issue1152248  и не понял, 9 лет (с 5-го по 14-й год) разработки чем завершились? Сейчас стандартно `file.readlines` позволяют задавать произвольный разделитель?

Comment: @avp: смысл ссылки на баг, чтобы увидеть обсуждение мотивации: зачем иметь разделитель отличный от  `b'\n'` и что реализация может быть сложнее чем кажется на первый взгляд. В stdlib я не знаю средств, которые позволяют произвольный разделить указывать. Обычно проще по потребностям подходящую к конкретному случаю реализацию написать или что-то вроде fdpexpect использовать.