# Как из элемента QByteArray получить его бинарное представление?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, битовые-операции

У меня есть `QByteArray` принятого через последовательный порт изображения. Каждый элемент `QByteArray` - это 1 пиксель (8бит), цвет от `0` до `255`. Мне необходимо из этого, базового изображения сформировать 8 картинок. Алгоритм генерации такой:
Берем младший (нулевой, правый) бит первого пикселя исходного изображения, если он равен `0`, то первый байт (пиксель) первого генерированного изображения должен быть черным (`'00000000'`, `'0x00'`, `0`), если же младший бит первого пикселя исходного изображения равен `1`, то первый байт(пиксель) первого генерированного изображения должен быть белым(`'11111111'`, `'0xFF'`, `255`). Также поступаем с первым битом первого пикселя исходного изображения, но формируем первый пиксель уже второго изображения, и так для первый пикселей всех оставшихся. Операцию повторяем для всех пикселей исходного изображения, тем самым формируя 8 двуцветных изображений.
С помощью `Python`, я алгоритм реализовал так:

```
def run(self):
    self.start_gen.emit(len(self.source_img))
    pb_val = 0
    for img in self.nine:
        self.nine[img] = bytearray(b'')
    for byte_ in self.source_img:
        pb_val += 1
        self.generating.emit(pb_val)
        bit_str = by2bi(byte_)
        for i in range(8):
            if bit_str[i] == '0':
                self.nine['img_' + str(i)] += self.b0
            else:
                self.nine['img_' + str(i)] += self.b255
    self.stop_gen.emit()
```

Но вот при переписывании всего этого дела на `C++`, возникли глупые проблемы из за отсутствия опыта.
Например, как мне привести элемент `QByteArray` к виду `'00001111'`, чтобы в цикле проходиться по битам и сравнивать их с нулем или единицей? Как мне сформировать байты `'0x00'` и `'0xFF'`, для записи в `QByteArray` каждой картинки?
Мне кажется, что надо все это дело побитовыми операциями решать, но как?
И еще, в `Python`, я просто беру и создаю словарь с массивами, для записи в них значений, как подобное сделать в `C++`? Я подумал, что следует формировать 
`QVector<QByteArray> generated_images;`
Однако, компилятор ругается, что невозможно формировать вектор наполненный `QByteArray`'ями.

Comment: "как мне привести элемент QByteArray к виду '00001111'" - никак, это совершенно не нужно для работы с битами. Если у вас есть переменная целого типа intVal, проверка n-ного бита (если нулевой бит - младший) на единицу выполняется так: if (intVal & (1<<n))...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да, я уже додумался=) Но спасибо, все-равно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и в Питоне тоже [не нужно байты в "01"-строки превращать, чтобы биты прочитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710117/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5#comment1061833_710117). На Питоне, `numpy` можно использовать, чтобы побитовые операции над многими числами проводить, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15911233/4279)

Comment: @jfs казалось бы при чем тут питон, да еще и с numpy? Приведенный выше пример вполне можно использовать и в питоне...

Comment: @jfs numpy, это конечно замечательно, но он мне экзешник до 30 метров раздувает, хотя я толком не тестил, в чем там за загвоздка была, просто отключил его. После того, как реализовал в C++, переписал также в PyQt5, в разы шустрее пошло, теперь подумываю вообще, версию питоновскую переделать с pyserial, на QSerialPort, может пошустрее пойдет дело. И вообще, после того, как познакомился с С++, переосмыслил многое, до этого, в Python, как обезъянка писал, не задумываясь особо...как на псевдокоде.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: *"при чем тут питон"* посмотрите на код в вопросе (на каком языке он по-вашему написан). *"да еще и с numpy"* -- автор решил на С++ написать вместо того, чтобы спросить как ускорить Питон код (numpy -- одно из решений. Посмотрите в конце [ответа на несколько примеров по оптимизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/23044)). *"можно использовать и в питоне"* -- да, ссылка как раз показывает, что я ещё 25 августа автору привёл выражение "(byte_ >> i) & 1".

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев если у вас специфические проблемы с Питоном, так и о них и спрашивайте. Это похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy): вместо того, чтобы исправить Питон-код, вы спрашиваете как на С++ сделать.

Comment: @jfs Я написал приложение на Python, потом решил, что надо иметь представление хоть об одном из C-подобных языков, а что может быть лучше практики? Вот и начал переписывать его-же на С++, a так как некоторые вещи, которые я реализовал на Python, не очевидно воспроизводились в Qt, задаю вопросы здесь. Да, я, скорее всего, сбросил кашу из головы сюда, а не задал полноценный вопрос. Следует ли его удалить?

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев суть в том что вы *можете* попробовать Питон код исправить (есть такая возможность), но конечно вы не *обязаны* это делать. Вопрос о С++ это отдельная тема. Если у вас возник такой вопрос, может кто-то ещё с похожей проблемой столкнётся. Если найдёте решение (даже в форме изменения постановки задачи), то можете опубликовать как свой ответ — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs Python код я уже поправил (спасибо, при использовании побитовых сравнений по маске, генерация происходит практически мгновенно). Сейчас переписываю с pyserial на QSerialPort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы произвести проверку указанного в вопросе вида, я воспользовался [советами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/23044) уважаемого `@jfs`, как итог - изображения генерируются практически мгновенно. Правда не знаю, надо ли очищать `QVector<char> tempVector;` после того как скидываю его в общий `QVector<QVector<char>>`? Ведь создаю я его для каждой картинки... По диспетчеру задачь, память вроде не утекает.

```
void ImgGenerator::generate_images(QByteArray main_image_data)
{
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; ++bit) {
        QVector<char> tempVector;
        image_generation_progress (bit);
        for (int pixel = 0; pixel < main_image_data.count (); pixel++) {
            int x = (int)main_image_data[pixel] >> bit;
            if (x & 1) {
                tempVector.push_back (white);
            } else {
                tempVector.push_back (black);
            }
        }
        generrated_images.push_back (tempVector);
    }
    images_generated (generrated_images);
    generrated_images.clear ();
}
```

Но это, что касается проверки и формирования изображений. Однако для красивого вывода в консоль `bit` - представления приходящих комманд, я сотворил во что:

```
QBitArray by2bi(QByteArray data)
{
    QBitArray bits(data.count()*8);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.count(); ++i) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
            bits.setBit( i * 8 + b , data.at(i) & (1<<(7 - b)) );
        }
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Создаю `QBitArray` из имеющегося сообщения, а затем форматирую всё это дело для вывода в консоль:

```
QString bi2str(QBitArray bits)
{
    QString tempStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.count(); i++) {
        tempStr+=bits.at(i)?'1':'0';
    }
    const int step = 8;
    const char delim = 'x';
    for (int i = 8; i < tempStr.count(); i+=step+1) {
        tempStr.insert(i, delim);
    }
    QStringList strings8chars = tempStr.split('x');
    QStringList temporari_str_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < strings8chars.size(); i++) {
        QString temp_string = strings8chars.at(i);
        temp_string.insert(4, "<span style=\"color:white;\"><b>_</b></span>");
        temporari_str_list.push_back(temp_string);
    }
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QByteArray dot_symb = codec->fromUnicode("<span style=\"color:white;\"><b>·</b></span>");
    QString final_joined_string = temporari_str_list.join(dot_symb);
    return final_joined_string;
 }
```

По итогу, выводится сообщение в служебную консоль в формате: `0110_0101·0110_1100·1101_1010·1100_0110` ,что согласитесь, более читабельно чем просто поток `bit` вида `01100101011011001101101011000110`.
Если кому-то, когда-нибудь, будут полезны приведенные мной примеры, буду счастлив.