# Что дешевле: форматирование или конкатенация?

Tags: python, строки, форматирование, benchmark

Например, мне надо задать строковую переменную, в которой надо указать номер потока.
Есть два варианта.
Первый - с помощью конкатенации:

```
name="Thread #" + foo
```

Второй - с помощью форматирования:

```
name="Thread #%i" % foo
```

Я знаю, что в python строки являются immutable типом, а значит операция конкатенации приведет к созданию новой переменной.
 А что на счет форматирования?

Comment: Тут сообщали, что [«CPython может иногда автоматически оптимизировать конкатенацию строк»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/178213), так что фиг знает даже

Comment: без измерений (а значит конкретного кода, входных данных, железа, версий ПО) рассуждения о микрооптимизациях большого смысла не имеют. Вы уверены, что создание имени потока является узким местом в вашем коде?

Comment: @jfs я волнуюсь не именно про этот конкретный случай. Я говорю в общем про оптимизацию работы со строками

Comment: "*в общем* про оптимизацию работы со строками" можно книгу написать. К примеру, [мой ответ, выше приведённый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/23044), пытается только один пример с `+=` оператором на строками разобрать (посмотрите на  размер ответа). Начните с `python  -mtimeit $'ваш код'` если какие-то результаты будут не ясны -- спрашивайте.

Comment: @andreymal: для ясности: случай `s = "a" + s` не оптимизирован насколько я знаю. Может быть оптимизирован случай: `s += "a"` если других ссылок на `s` нет (overallocation нет, поэтому для больших строк рано или поздно поведение всё равно станет квадратичным -- от realloc на платформе зависит как в ответ сказано).

Comment: @jfs отличную идею подкинули самом провести тест на скорость выполнения. Этим и займусь

Answer (score 8):

Конкатенация быстрее форматирования `%`. Но, немного медленнее (*кст, от запуска к запуску f-строки быстрее выполнялись, чем конкатенация*) будет использование f-строки, поэтому я бы рекомендовал использовать их, т.к. они удобнее

```
from timeit import timeit

foo = 'FooBar'
test_globals = dict(foo=foo)

t = timeit('name = "Thread #" + foo', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Total time: {t:.3f} sec')

t = timeit('name = "Thread #%s" % foo', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Total time: {t:.3f} sec')

t = timeit('name = "Thread #{}".format(foo)', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Total time: {t:.3f} sec')

t = timeit('name = f"Thread {foo}"', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Total time: {t:.3f} sec')
```

Результат:

```
Total time: 0.066 sec
Total time: 0.155 sec
Total time: 0.228 sec
Total time: 0.072 sec
```

Comment: `"Thread \{foo\}"` что это? Подстановки не происходит, поэтому и быстрее. f-string же `f"Thread {foo}"`. И тогда конкатенация дает лучший результат (на моей машине).

Comment: [pep-0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences)

Comment: @mkkik, опечатался и не проверил результат

Comment: для измерений лучше пользоваться специализированными модулями такими как timeit, perf, pytest-benchmark чтобы изобретая велосипед не получить квадратные колёса. Можно посмотреть, изменятся ли существенно результаты, если измерять разными способами, на других входных данных (больше одной переменной, к примеру). По меньшей мере, [замените time.clock() на timeit.default_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279)

Comment: @jfs, согласен, лучше было переписать, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно просто склеить две строки - используйте '+'. Если вам нужно склеить больше двух строк - используйте форматирование, как по мне - лучше `str.format`. Никогда не склеивайте строки через `+=`, лучше `list` + 'join'.

Comment: согласен со всеми 3 пунктами, но это не отвечает на вопрос "что дешевле".

Comment: Смотря как прочитать ответ) я описал три случая, и что в каждом конкретном случае дешевле.

Comment: В таком случае, следует результаты сравнения производительности добавить, которые не противоречат этим заявлениям. Можно добавить: что вместо `s = s + "a"` можно писать `s += "a"`. `f""` строки часто делают код читаемым: `f"{a}...{b}"` вместо `"{a}...{b}".format(**vars())` или вместо `"{a}...{b}".format(a=a, b=b)`

Comment: Сравнение да, можно сделать. Про f строки считаю, что код может и более читаемый, но менее очевидный, и более сложный в поддержке.

Comment: более читаемый код является как более очевидным так и как следствие проще в поддержке.

Answer (score 1):

Обычная конкатенация , судя результатам измерения в статье по ссылке, с помощью оператора '+' быстрее любых других в Python - https://tproger.ru/translations/speedy-string-concatenation-python/