# Оптимизация кода Python: stroka = stroka + str(line) + '\n' в цикле долго работает

Tags: python, sqlite, производительность

Имеется следующий кусок кода, который берет данные из базы-данных `SQLite`, затем загружает их (в виде текста) в клиентское приложение, но к сожалению **загрузка данных** работает очень уж долго, как сделать быстрее?

```
results = c.execute(select).fetchall()

stroka = ''
for line in results:
    stroka = stroka + str(line) + '\n'

self.ui.textEdit.setText(stroka)
```

Comment: Покажите запрос и соответствующий DDL. Какой объём данных этим запросом выгребается? Что конкретно означает "долго".

Comment: В цикле вы просто в строку собираете данные, разделяя `\n`? Попробуйте в одну строку: `text = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in results)` или так `text = '\n'.join(map(str, results))`. Конкантенация строк медленнее `join` работает. И тело в вашем коде можно упростить через оператор `+=` так: `stroka += str(line) + '\n'`

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо, через join стало работать быстрее!

Comment: Лучше не ждать получения всех строк из базы, а, используя генератор, вытягивать по одной и отображать

Comment: связанный вопрос [Непонятное замедление конкатенации в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710117/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю оптимизировать составление текста через замену конкатенации строк на `join`:

```
text = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in results)
```

или так:

```
text = '\n'.join(map(str, results))
```

Comment: Можно ещё вариацию на тему: `'\n'.join([result for [result] in c.execute(select)])` попробовать. [Объединение результатов в одну строку в sql выглядит сложнее](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/4279)

Comment: Согласен, но это уже на усмотрение автора, я бы сделал как вы предложили, только: `'\n'.join(result for (result,) in c.execute(select))`

Comment: как для производительности так и читаемости, `[]` лучше оставить (внутри join для эффективности, а внутри for для читаемости). Сравните: `python -mdis <<<'[result]=1'` vs. `python -mdis <<<'(result,)=1'` (идентичны).¶ `join([])` быстрее `join()`: `python -mtimeit -s 's=[("a",)]*10**3' '"\n".join([a for [a] in s])' ` vs. `python -mtimeit -s 's=[("a",)]*10**3' '"\n".join(a for [a] in s)'`

Comment: меня смущает что пишем `[result]`, хотя `sqlite3` возвращает кортеж. Про `[]` в `join` думал что по эффективности будет ровно наоборот, ошибался, согласен c читаемостью

Comment: поэтому я явно `python -mdis` команды привёл, чтобы вы явно увидели , что  `[]` и `(,)` слева от `=` делают (это специальный синтаксис: list, tuple тут не создаются).

Comment: @jfs, [Объединение результатов в одну строку конкретно в SQLite выглядит достаточно просто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758746/211923)

Comment: @MaxU: тесты показывают, что объединение на стороне базы данных ещё и быстрее может быть в несколько раз, чем тот же цикл в чистом Питоне.

Comment: @jfs, это не так уж и удивительно ;)

Comment: @MaxU: вы будете удивлены как часто самые "очевидные" предположения не переживают встречу с фактическими измерениями.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать это на стороне SQLite.

Пример:

```
sqlite> select * from tab;
s
----------
111
222
333

sqlite> select group_concat(s,'') from tab;
group_concat(s,'')
------------------
111222333

sqlite> select group_concat(s,'\n') from tab;
group_concat(s,'\n')
--------------------
111\n222\n333
```

в следующем варианте возвращается **одна** строка:

```
sqlite> select group_concat(s,char(10)) from tab;
group_concat(s,char(10))
------------------------
111
222
333
```

[Спасибо @jfs за код для Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758569/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-python-stroka-stroka-strline-n-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0/758746?noredirect=1#comment1174474_758746):

```
[[result]] = db.execute("select group_concat(s, '\n') from tab")
```

PS данный вариант имеет `O(n)` по времени выполнения

Comment: `[[result]] = db.execute("select group_concat(s, '\n') from tab")` Явно упомяните гарантии (`O(n)`) на время выполнения.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, добавил...