# Мониторинг Claymore с помощью Python

Tags: python, сокет

Здравствуйте!
Никак не могу написать простейший сетевой RAW-запрос с помощью Python....
Вот так выглядит запрос в шелле Убунту:

```
echo '{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}' | netcat localhost 3333
```

Вот так выглядит его вывод:

```
{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":["0.13.0rc7","121","172958;305;0","24619;24697;24697;24697;24775;24775;24697","0;0;0","off;off;off;off;off;off;off","54;70; 55;70; 52;65; 50;65; 52;65; 51;65; 56;70","pirl.minerpool.net:8004","0;0;0;0"]}
```

Пробую написать простенький скрипт на Pyton:

```
import socket
import json

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 3333))
s.send('{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}'.encode("utf-8"))
j=s.recv(2048)
s.close()
resp=json.loads(j.decode("utf-8"))
resp=resp['result']
print (resp)
```

И вот в этом месте - `j=s.recv(2048)` скрипт просто зависает, приходится выходить по CTRL-C.

Помогите, пожалуйста.... Что я делаю не так?

UPDATE!!!
Результаты экспериментов:
Запускаем, как подсказали сервер в другом шелле командой 
`nc -l -p 4444 <<< '{"result":1}'`
применяем к нему такую же строку опроса:
`echo '{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}' | netcat localhost 4444`
на выходе в шелле сервера видим эхо параметров:
`{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}`
в шелле запроса видим ответ сервера:
`{"result":1}`
т.е., работает. Запускаем скрипт, где предложено с сокетом как с файлом общаться. В окне сервера видим, что изменился порядок ключей: `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "miner_getstat1", "id": 0}` в окне клиента видим ответ просто `1`.
Все остальные варианты ответов тоже работают. Почему-то только не работает именно запрос к майнеру, хотя из командной строки шелла он прекрасно отрабатывает.....

Comment: На этой строчке у вас программа зависает, потому что вы ей сказали ждать 2048 байт данных. И пока они не придут программа будет "висеть". Можно ограничить время ожидания, например секундой при помощи метода `s.settimeout(1)`

Comment: @Avernial: `s.recv` может вернуться после прочтения даже **одного** байта. `2048` это размер буфера под результат (наибольшая длина), а не длина возвращаемого значения.

Comment: `s.send` может меньше  послать байт чем задано. Используйте `s.sendall`

Comment: @jfs Конечно может,  и вернёться, но в случае если установлено не бесконечное ожидание. Но если установлен блокирующий режим, то пока не прочитает 2048(не заполнит буфер) байт метод будет ждать.

Comment: @Avernial: неверно. `timeout` тут не имеет отношения к делу. Попробуйте: `nc -l -p 3333 <<< 'short answer'` сервер.

Comment: @jfs Да все верное пишете. Странно, казалось что есть такой вариант, когда блокируется `recv ` до заполнения буфера.

Comment: В общем, оба варианта ниже не сработали. Висит в обоих вариантах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас обычный TCP сокет. raw сокеты это ниже категория.

`socket.recv`, `socket.send` это относительно низкоуровневые функции. Для удобства, можно с сокетом как с файлом в Питоне работать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import os
import socket

request = {"id": 0, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "miner_getstat1"}
with socket.create_connection(('localhost', 3333)) as sock:
    sock.sendall(json.dumps(request).encode())
    sock.sendall(os.linesep.encode())
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)  # no more writing
    with sock.makefile('r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        response = json.load(file)
print(response['result'])
```

`os.linesep` (новая строка) добавлена на случай, если сервер ожидает http://jsonlines.org/ формат.

Comment: Этот вариант тоже висит

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov код в ответе работает с сервером, который принимает и отдаёт json ответы (по одному на соединение). Вы уверены, что всё ещё работает echo|nc  команда из вопроса? Появляется ли приглашение командной строки (завершилась ли nc команда?) Можно попробовать новую строку добавить в конце, если `echo -n` не работает (но это не должно влиять).¶ Вы уверены что сервер не ожидает тут http запрос?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/DhHqnGB.png  
Запущен скрипт и команда `echo | netcast` работает

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov вы запускали `echo -n` команду? Уверены, что правильный Питон скрипт запускаете. Совпадают ли запросы байт в байт (из  Питона и  из nc — проверьте с помощью `nc -l -p 4444 <<< '{"result":1}'` сервера) Если Ctrl C нажать, то что в traceback показано?

Comment: все варианты команды `nc -l -p 3333` выдают Address already in use. 
https://i.imgur.com/s6uRasj.png  исходная команда шелла `echo '{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}' | netcat localhost 3333` отрабатывает прекрасно. Если ваш вариант оборвать по CTRL-C, то видно вот это:   
`https://i.imgur.com/9itOllG.png

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov в моём комментарии написано-p 4444, а не -p 3333. Порт нужно поправить (и на клиентах тоже). Точный код и команды, результаты в вопрос как текст добавьте.

Comment: Запутался.... Майнер запускается такой строчкой: `ethminer --farm-recheck 6000 -U -S pirl.minerpool.net:8004 -O 0x6520e83467175fb3c3c466fc543174a936fb7950.ldv3 -SP 1 --api-port -3333` в конце и указан порт, на котором будут доступны данные. Надо его на 4444 переделать?

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov: нет. Чтобы проверить, что Питон и ваша echo|nc команда идентичные данные посылают, запустите  сервер  для теста:  `nc -l -p 4444 <<< '{"result":1}'` после этого запустите клиента. Повторите  с другим клиентом, сравните результаты.

Comment: Попробовал, как вы сказали. Результаты озадачили. Подробности изложил в вопросе

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov на случай у сервера json парсер сломанный, в sendall как есть запрос подставьте: `sock.sendall(b'{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}\n')`

Comment: Да! Этот кривой парсер требовал символ перевода строки в конце! Мало того, он еще и возвращает в конце такой же символ! Итоговый правильный скрипт дан во втором обновлении к вопросу

Comment: @jfc после добавления строки `sock.sendall(os.linesep.encode())` теперь вываливается ошибка `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov вы уверены что именно добавление linesep строчки повлияло? То есть вы хотите сказать: без этой строчки соединение висит без ответа, а с этой строчкой — неожиданно закрывается соединение? Опять таки: обычный json парсер игнорирует пробелы в конце, поэтому ему всё равно есть linesep или нет. У парсера, ожидающего новую строку, не должно быть причин ломаться: как  `b'\n'` так и  `b'\r\n'` естественно принимать. `os.linesep` используется, чтобы вывод можно было и другим программам скормить. На данном этапе, я бы посмотрел, что документация сервера гарантирует (чтобы понять что баг)

Comment: Да, именно так. Без это строчки - висит, с этой - вылетает. Документации к данному API нет, кроме приведенного примера. В принципе, не критично - вариант ниже прекрасно работает....

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov посмотрите на исходники тогда. Или можно руками перебрать возможные варианты: А- послать linesep в том же вызове sendall (не должно быть разницы один или два  sendall) Б- попробовать `b'\n'`, `b'\r\n'`, `b''`, `b'\r'` в качестве новой строки или повторения этого символа (на Убунту \n linesep) В- использовать collections.OrderedDict вместо словаря или просто руками в json объекте порядок элементов поменять (json объекты неупорядочены—любой порядок обычный парсер принимает) Г- пробелы добавить/ убрать в json separators=(',',':')(не внутри строк они игнорируются обычным парсером)

Answer (score 1):

```
j=s.recv(2048)
```

ожидает данные в количестве 2048 "символов". У вас в ответе гораздо меньше.

В простейшем варианте надо эту строчку заменить, как вариант, на подобную:

```
   while 1:
        data = s.recv(8)
        recv_data += data
        if not data or (len(data) < 8 and data[-2:] == ']}'):
            break 
   s.close()
```

Comment: [`s.recv(2048)` вовсе не ждёт 2048 байт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787120/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-claymore-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-python#comment1238022_787120). Можно убедиться, используя `nc -l -p 3333 <<< 'short answer'` сервер.

Comment: @jfs Да, я возможно неудачно употребил слово `ожидает`, и не имел ввиду здесь смысл `ждёт`.

Comment: суть в том, что `s.recv(2048)` может и один байт вернуть. Поэтому проблема у автора вопроса, не в величине ответа -- не поэтому `s.recv()` вызов висит. Скорее всего нужно просто send на sendall заменить автору, чтобы полностью запрос отправить.¶ Чтобы весь ответ прочитать, следует вызывать `s.recv` до тех пор пока нулевое количество не вернётся или с сокетом как с файлом работать как в моём ответе показано

Comment: тоже висит. пробовал send на senall поменять - тоже висит

Answer (score 1):

Вот и разобрались сообща! Действительно, этому кривому парсеру надо было дать в строку запроса символ перевода строки. Мало того, в выдаваемом ответе он в конце тоже пихает перевод строки, что затрудняет вылавливание выхода из бесконечного цикла. Вот итоговый, работающий, код:

```
import socket
import json

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 3333))
s.sendall('{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_getstat1"}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
resp = ''
while 1:
     data = s.recv(4096)
     resp += data.decode('utf-8')
     if not data or (len(data) < 4096 and data[-3:] == b']}\n'):
          break
s.close()
print (resp)
```

Огромное всем спасибо!

Comment: `data.decode('utf-8')` может у вас сломаться так как `s.recv()` не обязан целиком отдавать символы, которые несколько байт в utf-8 могут занимать. Декодируйте только получив полный ответ [`resp=bytearray() ... resp += data ... r = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/23044)¶ Отсутствие `\n` внутри json и наличие \n в конце наоборот помогать в разборе ответа: просто вызывайте `s.recv(4096)` пока `b''` не получите (eof) или пока `b'\n'` не встретите: `if not data or b'\n' in data: break`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Так и сделаю!